# How to guarantee clearance/creepage on mains side of an optocoupler used for 230VAC zero-crossing detection?

Tags: opto-isolator, safety, zero-crossing, ul

[image]

Update: Added a diode to protect optocoupler LED

As stated in several safety standards (UL 60950 or UL 60750 for example,) we have to guarantee a minimum clearance/creepage between signals of opposite polarities, like 230VAC LINE and NEUTRAL.

How is it possible between pin 1 and pin 2 of most optocouplers, like the one used in the partial schematic above?

Many time we've been asked to put some conformal coating over those pins, but is this the only solution to the problem?

---

I want to add to the discussion that the certifying body raised the non conformity starting from UL 197 table 37.1

[image]

This table sets a 4.0mm minimum distance between "uninsulated live parts of opposite polarity", but for me it is not applicable neither to this specific situation (asking to coat pin 1 and 2 because spacing is less than 4.0mm) neither to the whole PCB, because for me PCB tracks are not uninsulated (they are covered by solder mask).

Comment: I don't have an official answer, but are you aware that because there are resistors on the live wire, so it is not the live wire directly that goes to the optoisolator input, so is there even a creepage/clearance problem to begin with? Oh and won't the opto get damaged if there's 325V in reverse direction over the LED? Typically they can handle only about 5V in reverse.

Comment: I raised the same observation to certifying body, saying that on these pins we have far lower voltage, but still they consider it not valid.

Comment: About the second point, usually I put a diode between pin 1 and 2 with reverse polarity (it's not shown on the schematic because not relevant to the question).

Comment: It might be relevant. Because then there will never be more than 2V over the opto pins. What if you move one resistor to neutral and keep one on live?

Comment: @sgio The reverse diode is very relevant to the question, because it controls the voltage between pins 1 and 2. Without it, you could have 1500 V between those pins (mains flash), but even rated mains would destroy the coupler LED. With the diode, it's the two resistors that are subject to the mains flash, they do have >750 V rating each, don't they? You need 8 mm clearance between LED pins and transistor pins, that's why the package is pinned like that. Many people rout a slot in the board under the opto to guarantee the creepage distance.

Comment: @Neil_UK I've update the schematics to include that diode.

Comment: My problem is not the clearance/creepage between LED and transistor pin, but between LED pins 1 and 2.

Comment: @sgio - Hi, Your "answer" (which wasn't a full answer to your original question, and therefore should not have been posted in the "Your Answer" box) has now been added to the question as an edit (i.e. an update) instead. Unless you are writing the *full* & final answer to your own question (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself, with no further help needed) please don't use the "Your Answer" box below. Instead, you should edit the question to add new information, test results etc. (This is one way that Stack Exchange differs from forums. See the [tour] & [help] for more rules.)

Answer (score 1):

UL60950 has a table inside that allows you to find the correct value of clearance and creepage between the **primary side** and the **secondary side**, starting from:

1. Voltage difference
2. Pollution degree of the environment where the product will be installed

In that norm, on the primary side you should look for the words "functional distances".

The meaning of "**functional distances**" is: "the UL safety engineer does not really care about problems on the primary side."

That's what functional mean from the UL60950 point of view.

At 230 VAC in a pollution degree environment set to 2 the minimum cleareance is 2.4 mm and almost all optocouplers will do because you are on the primary side.

---

You should care about clearance and creepage between the primary side and the secondary one.

---

If your optocoupler meets those requirements the UL Safety engineer will, in any case, short LINE and NEUTRAL to see if the mandatory fuse trips.

It the **fuse trips** than the test is marked as PASS.

The fuse must be placed on the LINE track of your PCB and must be an **UL60950 recognized** part.

---

Take a look at this part and its UL File E52744 available on UL database:

[image: Front page pf Vishay CNY17 optocoupler datasheet]

<sub>Image source: [Vishay CNY17 optocoupler datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83606/cny17.pdf)</sub>

Ciao

Comment: Thank you

Board is inside a metal box, not reachable from the user. They are certified considering Pullution Degree II, Material Group IIIa/IIIb: in fact there is no risk of conductive dirt and/or persistent moisture. Resistors are always above 600V minimum, but it depends on specific availability. For years we got no problem with this kind of configuration

Comment: And CNY17-4 (for example) has a 2.54mm pitch, so it should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

If the two 33k resistors are doing their job, then there
Should only be about 1.5V between pins 1 and 2 of the optocoupler.

Pin 1 is effectively at neutral voltage.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a problem regarding leakage between pins 1 and 2. The voltage between them is clamped to a few volts.

You may have other problems as a consequence of your mains connection.

The series resistors will be subject to normal mains overvoltages, typically 1500 V, so should be rated at least 750 V each, maybe even need a certification for mains use.

You may have a clearance/leakage problem from pins 1 and 2 to other areas of your build. Typically you need 4 mm of direct distance (clearance) and 8 mm of surface path (creepage) between the live pins (the mains entry terminals, series resistors, opto pins 1,2), and conductors that may come into contact with people (for instance the chassis, whatever is connected to pins 4,5,6, and any other low voltage tracks). The live terminals may require physical shielding so that they cannot be accidentally touched.

I realise you have said that the certification board don't like what you are proposing. Bear in mind that they are concerned with public safety. If it sounds to them as if you don't know what you're doing (and omitting that diode across the opto on your first presentation of the schematic made it sound like you did not know what you were doing) then they are likely to reject what you say as a matter of course. You need to up your game. Research what regulations are current in your area. You have a lot of catching up to do to restore your standing with them.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I've already certified lots of EN 60335 boards without any problem, until recently a certifying body started asking us to cover with conformal coating LED pins of every optocoupler exposed to mains with the motivation that these pins could be exposed to mains.
We're using proper resistors (two in series for safety), proper protection diodes and proper clearance/creepages spacinges everywhere: same configuration as always (certified without any problem).
Now a new cert body technician is asking us to add conformal coating.
My question is, why?

Comment: @sgio see my comment about inadvertently touching them, or are you going to be using this board in a harsh environment where condensation or contamination on the board might be a problem? Just curious, what is the rating of those resistors?

Comment: Board is inside a metal box, not reachable from the user.
They are certified considering Pullution Degree II, Material Group IIIa/IIIb: in fact there is no risk of conductive dirt and/or persistent moisture.
Resistors are always above 600V minimum, but it depends on specific availability.

For years we got no problem with this kind of configuration.